# Accessing Macro variables using Proc sql

Tags: sas

I am using the following code to generate a macro variable:

```
proc sql;
   select count(*) into :Nobs 
   from table1;
   select variable_list into :val1-:val%left(&Nobs) 
   from table1;
quit;
```

I would now like to use this variable list to subset a particular data set. I could do this with individual macro variables as follows:

```
data subset_data;
   set original_data;
   where variable = "&val1";
run;
```

My question is, in the where condition how could I check for all the values in the val array?

Comment: Your question is not clear. &val1-&val2 will have values. How do you want to check those values?  Suggest you show the data in table1.  And show the SAS data step code you would like to generate.

Comment: There is no need to pre-count the number of values.  You can use `:val1-` to indicate an unbounded list of macro variables. The automatic macro variable SQLOBS will have the count if you need it for something else.  If you have an old version of SAS that does not support that syntax then just use an upper bound that is larger than any possible count. `:var1-:var99999`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the IN () operator. "Arrays" of macro variables are usually more work than they are worth.  Instead just store all of the values into a single macro variable. If your values are numbers then use this:

```
proc sql noprint;
select variable
  into :value_list separated by ' ' 
  from table1
;
quit;
data subset_data;
  set original_data;
  where variable in (&value_list);
run;
```

If your variables are character variables then use the QUOTE() function so that you generate quoted strings instead of numbers.

```
select quote(trim(variable))
  into :value_list separated by ' ' 
  from table1
;
```